# IBM BlueMix Node-RED not displaying the sensor values

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot

My mobile android device was connected successfully to my dashboard and i can visualize all my sensors values on real time.

The problem is that these values cannot be displayed in Node-RED even though that i have followed all the instructions provided on this [guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/iot-smartphone-sensor-actuator-bluemix-apps-trs/index.html).

Why these values cannot be displayed?

P.S: Debugging button is enabled.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The IoT Platform is in the same Bluemix Space as the NodeRed application? And if you do 'All' for devices it still doesn't show up?  I rarely trust 'bluemix services'.  In your IoT Platform, under 'Apps' you can generate API keys.  Then in your NodeRed, use API keys instead to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Select 'All' for Device Id and type 'accel' into the Event text field. You input node is showing connected.